# Alsa snd-aloop: add more loopback subdevices?

Tags: linux-kernel, audio, alsa, loopback

I'm currently working on a project on which I need to create multiple audio streams using `snd-aloop`. The issue is that we reach the max number of substreams easily.

Is it possible to have more than 8 subdevices on a loopback virtual sound card? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Increase `MAX_PCM_SUBSTREAMS` in `sound/drivers/aloop.c`.